# Solr auto delete using default value of ttl field

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am trying to use Solr auto-delete feature with solr-6. I have made the following changes in my managed-schema.xml and solrconfig.xml.

managed-schema

```
<!--expiration date field-->
<field name="eDate" type="date" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="ttl" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true" default="+90SECONDS"/>
```

solrconfig

```
<processor class="solr.processor.DocExpirationUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <int name="autoDeletePeriodSeconds">30</int>
    <str name="ttlFieldName">ttl</str>
    <str name="expirationFieldName">eDate</str>
</processor>
```

I am able to use auto delete feature as expected if I explicitly set the ttl field either in the incoming document or if I set the ttl request parameter in the update request.
However, I want to use a default value for ttl as specified in the managed-schema if I do not explicitly set the ttl field. When I try this, ttl field is generated with the default value but the corresponding eDate field is not generated.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do?
If yes, then how can I do this? Please leave a comment if you need any further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't make it working via `default` param in `field` description, but I make it working via adding `solr.DefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory`

In my update chain I have this:

```
    <processor class="solr.DefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <str name="fieldName">ttl</str>
        <str name="value">+15SECONDS</str>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.processor.DocExpirationUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <int name="autoDeletePeriodSeconds">5</int>
        <str name="ttlFieldName">ttl</str>
        <str name="expirationFieldName">eDate</str>
    </processor>
```

I change values to have a quicker test :) Link to the working [code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/master/lucene5/src/main/scala/org/mystic/AutoDelete.scala)

Comment: Any idea why it is not working for default field directly in the schema? Because we do not want to pass the TTL for every document from our code. I think adding "default" keyword in the field property should internally be triggering this update processor?

Comment: my answer do not require to pass TTL for every document. have no idea why it's not working through schema param

Comment: @Mysterion I am storing documents using parent child relationship. My ttl and eDate fields are only generated for parent documents and not child documents. Do you know a way to remedy this? Update request is sent via java solr client's commit method.

Comment: plz create another question about default field values for child docs with code, etc